# how to refer SQLite SIMPLE way in Javascript-App just use 'DB_open, execute SQL..' VS2012

Tags: javascript, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, transactions

I want to write an App (JS) with SQLite (VS2012). So I can't find a easy beginnerguide for this. When I install the *SQLite for Windows Runtime*. There is a C++ code (GitHub) to insert in the Projekt. 
So, what happens with the JS - Projekt? 
How can JS refer to properties and methodes of the DB-Objekt (dll, ocx, whatever from the SQLite-Runtime) just to open DB, execute SQL etc. in a simple way?

In Android-Browser following **simple JS code (no more)** is korrekt:

```
    var shortName = 'testDb';
    var version = '1.0';
    var displayName = 'test db';
    var maxSize = 1048576; // in bytes
    mydb = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);

     function(transaction) {
          transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person(id INTEGER ..);', [], NullDataHandler, errorHandler);
}
```

Is somebody here - can show me the same SIMPLE in VS2012 without an Overhead, advanced settings and error-mangement - I can't follow the code?
1. DB_open : ..
2. Execute SQL : ..

Many Greetings from Bavaria
ralphi
PS: Why isn't it allowed to insert links?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your Javascript is running on a web page. Actually, There is no way to manipulate the Sqlite database from a web page. For security reason, the ability to access local files from a web page is strictly limited.  Despite new HTML5-supported browsers allow you to access  local files in a limited and safe way,  directly using local database is not possible in HTML world.